# serve static image along side java google-endpoint api

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

In Python to host a basic website on app-engine, I can put all my image files in a static directory, say img, and then in the yaml file have

```
- url: /img
 static_dir: img
```

then to access my images, I simply do `myid.appspot.com/img/pic.jpeg`

I need to do the same thing for a Java google-endpoint backend. How would that work? I am using the Google-eclipse-plugin. I suppose I need to edit the `web.xml` file. But I am not sure what I would put in there.

The structure of my `/img` directory is such that it in turn contains many directories, each with images in them. For example: `/img/famousActors/willSmith.jpeg`.

Ref [storing static images in the blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509796/storing-static-images-in-the-blobstore/16509856?noredirect=1#16509856)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles), putting them in a folder other than `WEB-INF` is all you have to do.

> By default, App Engine makes all files in the WAR available as static files except JSPs and files in WEB-INF/. Any request for a URL whose path matches a static file serves the file directly to the browser—even if the path also matches a servlet or filter mapping.

A request to `/img/famousActors/willSmith.jpeg` should work without additional configuration.

Comment: I will try it out and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting this exception when trying to read the filenames on the server side? `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"`. I can view the image if I type the url. But when I try to read from the server itself, I get the error.

Comment: You can answer here if you know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513260/java-security-accesscontrolexception-file-accessible-thru-browser-but-not-withi