# java.security.AccessControlException: File accessible thru browser but not within same server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-io, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

So to not repeat myself too much, please refer to [serve static image along side java google-enpoint api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510724/serve-static-image-along-side-java-google-enpoint-api).

As you can see from the referenced link, I am able to view the image through the url. However, when I am trying to read filenames using similar code to

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}

final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

I get a security exception

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/myImages" "read")
```

Does anyone know the fix? How come the call thru the browser show the image and yet a call from within the server itself throws an exception? I find that strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configured a file as a "static" resource, it'll be served up by a separate pool of servers that are optimized for serving static content. A consequence is that the file isn't available to be opened from your app. "resource" files are available for the app to open and read.

That's documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files).

You'll need to use a relative path when opening a resource. You've shown an absolute path above.

Comment: On localhost it was easy to find the path to my static files. Now that I have deployed, it's not at `myapi@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/images/willsmith.jpg` as I would expect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the server is running as a service, make sure that service has permissions to the folder and files you're trying to read.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Recall: I can reach the file thru the browser but not from within the same server and yet the folder in question is inside the war directory.

Comment: What's the URL you're using to get to the file in your browser?
Also, what OS are you running this on and what app server?