# Sending inline images javaMail Google App Engine with Map

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

Having difficulty getting an email to send over a Google App Engine project using the default JavaMail service when adding an inline image to it. Can't understand why it's not sending. It works fine when i don't have an imagePart. Does anyone know what im doing wrong here? Or how i can go about debugging this? Much appreciated. Thanks...

```
    public void run(){

         try{
                //email body
                String htmlMessage = "<html>Hi there,<br>";
                htmlMessage += "See this cool pic: <img src=\"cid:ID1\" />";
                htmlMessage += "And this cool pic: <img src=\"cid:ID2\" />";
                htmlMessage += "</html>";

                //image part
                Map<String, String> inlineImages = new HashMap<String, String>();
                inlineImages.put("ID1", "/img/home-icon.png");
                inlineImages.put("ID2", "https://storage.googleapis.com/logophilia/default/Logophilia.png");

                //send to
                String useremail = "some.email@gmail.com";

                //email method below
                sendImage(useremail,htmlMessage,inlineImages);    
         }    
}
```

This method below is how the email gets sent.

```
 public static void sendImage(String useremail, String htmlBody,
                Map<String, String> mapInlineImages){

            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            //app engine requires this for some reason
            String msgBody = "...";

            try {
              Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
              msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("someaddress.mail@gmail.com", "An Image test from website"));
              msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(useremail, "Admin"));
              msg.setSubject("Image test");
              msg.setText(msgBody);

            // creates message part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");

            // creates multi-part
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // adds inline image attachments
            if (mapInlineImages != null && mapInlineImages.size() > 0) {
                Set<String> setImageID = mapInlineImages.keySet();

                for (String contentId : setImageID) {
                    MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" + contentId + ">");
                    imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);

                    //commenting out the stuff below makes it work...
                    String imageFilePath = mapInlineImages.get(contentId);
                    try {
                        imagePart.attachFile(imageFilePath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);


                }
            }

            msg.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(msg);

            } catch (AddressException e) {
                  // ...
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                  // ...
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                  // ...
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the attachFile method to attach something that's not a file (ID2), it's a URL.  Use this instead:

```
imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new URL(imageFilePath)));
```

I assume `/img/home-icon.png` is a locally accessible file.

Also, you probably want to create a multipart/related instead of the default multipart/mixed:

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
```

Comment: Awesome thanks man, finally getting somewhere! So it was all about that "related" part that i missed out. Thanks for the info on the URL thing also. 

One quick question if you don't mind, I got this following error:

"java.security.AccessControlException
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/img/home-icon.png" "read")
sendImage" 

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out in the end. The problem was that i didn't have a relative URL. It has to be  "inlineImages.put("ID1", "img/home-icon.png");". And not, " inlineImages.put("ID1", "/img/home-icon.png");". More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513260/java-security-accesscontrolexception-file-accessible-thru-browser-but-not-withi